# Why there is a gap between Keyboard and the View when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

**Structure:**

*UIView*

> BaseView

*AutoLayout*

> 1. Center X
> 2. Center Y
> 3. Equal Width to SafeView
> 4. Equal Height to SafeView

---

*UIView*

> InnerView (SubView of BaseView)

*AutoLayout*

> 1. Leading
> 2. Trailing
> 3. Top
> 4. Bottom (Create the IBOutLet named "bottomLayoutConstraint")

---

```
    - (void)keyBoardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

        NSDictionary *info  = notification.userInfo;
        NSValue      *value = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
        CGRect rawFrame      = [value CGRectValue];
        CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:rawFrame fromView:nil];
        self.bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame);
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    }

    - (void)keyBoardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

        self.bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = 0.0;

    }
```

---

Why there is a gap between `Keyboard` and the `InnerView` when keyboard appears?

[image]

---

**Edit:**

After applying Aleksander Maj's solution the gap reduced to 5px

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Here is my View hierarchy screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame)` returns the height of the keyboard counting from the **bottom edge of the screen**. Meanwhile your `bottomLayoutConstraint` is pinned to your **`BaseView`'s safe area's bottom edge** (which is not the same as the bottom edge of the screen). The difference between those two horizontal guides is the height of your gap.
You should calculate the constant of the `bottomLayoutConstraint` in the following way:

```
if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
  self.bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame) - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
} else {
  self.bottomLayoutConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame)
}
```

At least that's what I suspect. I didn't reproduce your view hierarchy.

---

EDIT:

Could you paste a screenshot of your view hierarchy (with all constraints expanded)? I think your issue with the 5pt gap may have something to do with incorrect constraint constant values.

[image: View hierarchy]

---

EDIT 2:

[image: Safe Area's centerY]

Comment: Thanks for Replying, kindly view the edits and new screenshot I added in my question, which show after applying your solution gap reduced to 5px. Why still 5px gap remaining?

Comment: There might be a second problem in your view hierarchy. See my edited answer.

Comment: Kindly view View hierarchy screenshot in my question.

Comment: `BaseView.centerY = centerY` is the one that's causing issues. You shoud constrain your `BaseView`'s `centerY` to **Safe Area's** `centerY`.

It should say `BaseView.centerY = Safe Area.centerY`